# Replacing the first column values according to the second column pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to use regex to replace values in Data Frames, here, 5th column according to pattern of the 1st column? The column 5 consist only in ones for now. However, I would like to start changing this column when in the 1st column pattern 34444 appears. Then program suppose to replace ones with 11111, 22222, 33333 etc. until the end of the file when the pattern appears.

Sample of the file:

```
             0  5  1            2           3           4
11           1  1  1  -173.386856   -0.152110  -58.235509
12           2  1  1  -176.102464   -1.020643   -1.217859
13           3  1  1  -175.792961  -57.458357  -58.538891
14           4  1  1  -172.774153  -59.284206   -1.988605
15           5  1  1  -174.974179  -56.371161  -58.406157
16           6  1  3   138.998480   12.596951    0.223780
17           7  1  4   138.333252   11.884713   -0.281429
18           8  1  4   139.498084   13.356891   -0.480091
19           9  1  4   139.710930   11.981460    0.697098
20          10  1  4   138.452807   13.136061    0.990663
21          11  1  3   138.998480   12.596951    0.223780
22          12  1  4   138.333252   11.884713   -0.281429
23          13  1  4   139.498084   13.356891   -0.480091
24          14  1  4   139.710930   11.981460    0.697098
25          15  1  4   138.452807   13.136061    0.990663
```

Expected result:

```
             0  5  1            2           3           4
11           1  1  1  -173.386856   -0.152110  -58.235509
12           2  1  1  -176.102464   -1.020643   -1.217859
13           3  1  1  -175.792961  -57.458357  -58.538891
14           4  1  1  -172.774153  -59.284206   -1.988605
15           5  1  1  -174.974179  -56.371161  -58.406157
16           6  1  3   138.998480   12.596951    0.223780
17           7  1  4   138.333252   11.884713   -0.281429
18           8  1  4   139.498084   13.356891   -0.480091
19           9  1  4   139.710930   11.981460    0.697098
20          10  1  4   138.452807   13.136061    0.990663
21          11  2  3   138.998480   12.596951    0.223780
22          12  2  4   138.333252   11.884713   -0.281429
23          13  2  4   139.498084   13.356891   -0.480091
24          14  2  4   139.710930   11.981460    0.697098
25          15  2  4   138.452807   13.136061    0.990663
```

Comment: Regex search works on strings, not on numeric arrays. [Do not assign the means of solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) unless you are forced to do so.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How to do it in the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if you really want `re`, there is a way. But I doubt it would be really more efficient than a for-loop.

### 1. re.finditer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

# present col1 as number-strings
arr1 = df['1'].values
str1 = "".join([str(i) for i in arr1])

ans = np.ones(len(str1), dtype=int)

# when a pattern is found, increase latter elements by 1    
for match in re.finditer('34444', str1):
    e = match.end()
    ans[e:] += 1

# replace column 5   
df['5'] = ans

# Output
df[['0', '5', '1']]
Out[50]: 
     0  5  1
11   1  1  1
12   2  1  1
13   3  1  1
14   4  1  1
15   5  1  1
16   6  1  3
17   7  1  4
18   8  1  4
19   9  1  4
20  10  1  4
21  11  2  3
22  12  2  4
23  13  2  4
24  14  2  4
25  15  2  4
```

### 2. naïve for-loop

Checks the array directly element-by-element. By comparison with `re.finditer`, no typecasting is involved, but an explicit for-loop is written. The same output is obtained. Please benchmark by yourself if efficiency became relevant, say, if there were tens of millions of rows involved.

```
arr1 = df['1'].values
ans = np.ones(len(str1), dtype=int)
n = len(arr1)

for i, el in enumerate(arr1):

    # termination
    if i > n - 5:
        break

    # ignore non-3 elements
    if el != 3:
        continue

    # if found, increase latter elements by 1
    if np.all(arr1[i+1:i+5] == 4):
        ans[i+5:] += 1

df['5'] = ans
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly! I was suggested by regex when I was looking for the way of solving problem that is why I was thinking at the beginning that it was the easiest method.

Comment: Thank you. In a sense, the `re` strategy may be preferable because it avoids explicit implementation over pattern matching and messing around with the indices. Just remember the limitation: `re` works on `str` only. Say, if your data contains numbers of 2 or more digits, then it won't work (for example, 23, 3 and 2, 33 will become indistinguishable.)